# How to integrate third party documents with the SharePoint search?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services, microsoft-search

I have a document management system where the documents are stored on AWS S3 and document metadata is stored in a NoSQL database. I want to integrate this with the SharePoint search. So that when a user search on Sharepoint that particular user should be able to see the search results from SharePoint documents + documents from the 3rd party system.
What are the steps that I need to follow in order to integrate the documents in my application to Sharepoint search?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect more data sources to Microsoft Search, here's a list of existing connectors:

[Microsoft Graph connectors overview for Microsoft Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftsearch/connectors-overview#what-data-sources-can-be-connected-to-microsoft-search)

If the existing connectors don't fulfil your requirements, you can create your own custom connector:

[Microsoft Graph connectors overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/connecting-external-content-connectors-overview)

Comment: Thanks, @Callum for your swift response. So if I can get my data into the Microsoft Graph, then it can be easily integrated with Sharepoint search, right? So that I can show the data from my database (imported to ms graph) in SharePoint search results?

Comment: In to Microsoft Search, yes. Most of modern SharePoint uses Microsoft Search, so that should cover most use cases.